# JSOUP HTML Parser

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

Is there a way to get **start line & column number** and **end line & column number** of element/tag ?

I am creating HTML editor that needs to highlight tag for speed optimization based on some scenario by given **start and end line & column number**.

Comment: I forked Jsoup and track the start and end position of all elements in the source document. I don't have column numbers and line numbers, but maybe this could be a start for you. You can find the code [here](https://github.com/tvogels/jsoup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately this is not possible with jsoup at the current time.

> At the moment Jsoup does not track line numbers / character positions
>   when parsing, so it's not possible to extract them. As this is not a
>   core use case, I don't want to extend the memory requirements of the
>   DOM by retaining this data. I have thought about possibly adding an
>   optional side-channel way to track it during the parse, in a similar
>   way as how parse errors can be tracked, but haven't focused on
>   implementing that yet.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsoup/lnbYSIZApWw

Instead, you could try [Jericho HTML Parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html). In its list of features it says:

> The row and column number of each position in the source document are
>   easily accessible.

See the javadocs [here](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/Source.html#getRowColumnVector%28int%29) and look into methods such as `getRow()`, `getColumn()`, and `getRowColumnVector()`.

Comment: Is there any other Java HTML Parser that track line numbers ?

Comment: @user2998596 Have you looked into [Jericho HTML Parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html)? In the features list is says `The row and column number of each position in the source document are easily accessible.` It has methods such as `getRow()`, `getColumn()`, and `getRowColumnVector()`.